# How to make use Hausdorff-Young inequality to make the following conclusion?

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I hope someone here can explain the following statement I read from the book stochastic differential equation and diffusion process written by Ikeda and Watanabe.

On page 186 of chapter IV of the book, it states the following:
[image] 
I would like to ask how one can apply Hausdorff Young inequality to conclude statement 1?

Answer (score 0):

The result that's usually called the [Hausdorff–Young inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff%E2%80%93Young_inequality) (about the Fourier transform on $L^p$ spaces) is not what we want here. The authors refer to [Young's inequality for convolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young's_inequality#Young.27s_inequality_for_convolutions), specifically: 
$$\|\nu_\lambda * f\|_p \le \|\nu_\lambda\|_1 \|f\|_p$$
Here, 
$$\|\nu_\lambda\|_1 = \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t} \|g_t\|_1 \,dt= 1/\lambda$$
because $g_t$ is nonnegative and $\|g_t\|_1=1$.